# pymongo failed due to exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

This is my function

```
def get_db_data(codes, collection, projection_list):
  try:
    project = {'$project': dict(map(lambda x: (x.replace('.','_'),'$%s'%x), projection_list),_id=0, code=1)}
    db_data = db[collection].aggregate([{'$match': {'code':{'$in':codes}}}, project])
    return dict( map(lambda x: (x.get('code'), x), db_data['result']) )
  except IndexError:
    return {}
```

here projection_list is

```
['fundamental.current_ratio', 'ebscore.latest_year.rating', 'pro_valuation.result', 
 'company_profile.profile', 'fundamental.yield', 'intelliquants.observation_period', 
 'fundamental.roa', 'fundamental.roe', 'pro_valuation.percentage_diff',
 'fundamental.tpftotalpromoter.S','intelliquants.avg_returns', 'fundamental.tptotalpublic.S',
 'fundamental.ttmnp', 'fundamental.reported_eps', 'Nicdata.description', 'fundamental.ttmeps',
 'fundamental.roce', 'pro_technical.result', 'ebscore.latest_year.result', 'company_equity.mcap',
 'fundamental.total_debt_equity', 'intelliquants.highest_monthly_returns', 'intelliquants.percentage_positive',
 'fundamental.pat_margin', 'fundamental.pshftotalpromoter.S', 'ebscore.latest_year.rationale', 
 'pro_valuation.final_value', 'intelliquants.worst_monthly_returns']
```

I know the full result of the aggregate call cannot be larger than 16 MB.

How can i do this with map reduce function or any other function in mongodb. I wish to have the same format what aggregate function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the issue is the that the size of the collection is too big, one option is to use the skip keyword and a loop to return smaller documents on a subset of the collections, and then merge them together yourself. So, for instance, here's an example that I dealt with recently:

```
def cross_query(collection, id_list, start_date, end_date, limit, skip):
    results = collection.aggregate([
        { "$match" : stuff}, 
        { "$group" : stuff},
        { "$unwind": stuff},
        { "$group" : stuff},
        { "$sort": stuff},
        { "$skip" : skip },
        { "$limit": limit}
    ])
    return results["result"]

def query(collection, id_list, start_date, end_date, limit):
    over = limit % 250000
    combined_results = []
    for i in range(limit / 250000):
        combined_results += cross_query(collection, id_list, start_date, end_date, 250000, 250000 * i))

    if over:
        combined_results += cross_query(collection, id_list, start_date, end_date, over, (limit / 250000) * 250000))

    return combined_results
```

So this takes a limit, say 850000, and proceeds to return the first 250000 results, then the next 250000, then the next 250000, then the last 100000. For the size of each result, the 250000 mark fit comfortably inside 16mb.

Comment: I don't have time to fully implement the function, and I especially couldn't test it. I've given an example, and it should be a simple as adding the {$skip : skip_var} operation to the list in aggregate, then wrapping everything in a loop.